# Create a link to compare tags in Gitlab markdown

Tags: markdown, gitlab, gitlab-8

We keep a changelog.md in the root of our gitlab projects and would like to include a link in each version tag to compare it to the previous tag.

The link needs to be e.g `https://gitlab.company.com/group/project/compare/v15.4.0...v15.3.0`

All relative links in markdown that I've tried end up relative to the current branch (including master) e.g. 
`[v15.4.0](compare/v15.3.0...v15.4.0)`, `[v15.4.0](../compare/v15.3.0...v15.4.0)` and `[v15.4.0](../../compare/v15.3.0...v15.4.0)`
all end up with the link
`https://gitlab.company.com/group/project/branch/compare/v15.3.0...v15.4.0`

Is there a way to create a link relative to the project root rather than the current branch?

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I have the same problem, all my changelog links to compare tags version are broken. I have researched in gitlab doc but nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately we have not found a solution yet @BorjaTur. I will update here if we do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least as of v12.6.4-ee the `[v15.4.0](../compare/v15.3.0...v15.4.0)` syntax generates the correct comparison link.

I have been unable to find an issue etc where this behaviour was changed so unknown exactly which version it was in.